# Access WCF Callback Service form Android (Bidirectional channel between WCF & Android)

Tags: c#, android, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-callbacks

I am using my WCF service from Android by making my service RESTFUL and using basicHttpBinding. My question is: Is it possible for android client (or any non microsoft client) to call a WCF service that implements callback? If not, any idea that can act like a Bidirectional channel between WCF & Android?

Comment: Yes.As my knowledge generally in WCF services for loading/getting images from server mostly writing callback events.we can call these services from android.

Comment: why you are using basicHttpBinding.Check with wsHttpBidning.

Comment: wsHttpBidning can be accessed by Android using any Soap library, but currently the available soap library for Android is v1.1 and wsHttpBidning uses Soap v1.2 which is not fully supported in Android. So using basicHttpBinding makes the service REST which can be accessed using http GET & POST from any platform

Comment: any help will be appreciated